# Typescript enum static checking

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm still not sure how to make sense of typescript enums.

Consider this:

```
enum Int { a, b };
const array: Int[] = [];
array.push(Int.a); // ok
array.push(0); // same
array.push(1); // this is b
array.push(123); // works
array.push(-3e6); // also works
```

So any `number` is compatible to `Int` ??

I'm aware that I can dynamically check since the `enum` declaration also generates an object declaration, unless we use `const enum`. But I was exprecting the static type to be `0 | 1` and not `number`.

Now for string enums:

```
enum Str { a = 'a', b = 'b' };
const array: Str[] = [];
array.push(Str.a); // ok
array.push('a'); // fails
```

So coming from the previous exemple, one might have thought that `Str` would be compatible with `string`, but no. It's not event compatible with `"a" | "b"`.

Can someone help me make sense of that ?

Specifically, I'm looking at some insight on why things work this way, and is there a way to have the compiler check things for us ?

Comment: Just for fun - using `type IntKeys = keyof Int; type NumberKeys = keyof number;` reveals that numeric enum keys are indeed number, those types are the same ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked at the [typescript discord](https://discord.com/invite/typescript), and apparently, `enum`s are **un**officially deprecated. Enums have been introduced in the language *before* union types and many other features we have today.

For typechecking only, one can use literal union types, like:

```
type Int = 0 | 1;
```

or

```
type Str = 'a' | 'b';
```

And if you also need runtime checking you can declare the runtime object as `const` and then use `typeof` to build the type. This is more flexible than enums because you choose how to encode the runtime object.

For exemple as an array:

```
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'] as const;
type Color = typeof colors[number]; // 'red' | 'green' | 'blue'
```

Or as a map:

```
const colors = {
  red: '#ff0000',
  green: '#00ff00',
  blue: '#0000ff'
} as const;
type Color = keyof typeof colors; // 'red' | 'green' | 'blue';
```

Or do more complex things, like associate keys with functions that you can't do with plain `enum`. The only downside is the declaration is a little more verbose than with enums, but I think the better type-checking and extra control on runtime encoding is worth it.